# Local acceleration of mirror in flat 1+1 spacetime

Tags: special-relativity, reflection, hawking-radiation, redshift

**Setup:** I am reading a paper (Carlitz and Willey. Phys.Rev.D. Vol35. pp.2327-2335. 1987) where the authors model Hawking radiation using a point-like accelerating "mirror" in 1+1 dimensional flat spacetime.

Suppose that the mirror's trajectory is described by a function $p(u)$ which is related to the red-shift of a photon reflected off the moving mirror via

\begin{equation}
p'(u)=\frac{1+\dot{x}_m}{1-\dot{x}_m}, \tag{CW 3.8} \label{1}
\end{equation}

where $x_m(t)$ is the $x$-coordinate of the mirror in inertial Cartesian coordinates $(t,x)$ and $u$ is the null coordinate $u\equiv t-x$.

Now, it is claimed that the local acceleration of the mirror is given by

\begin{equation}
\kappa (u) = -\partial_u \ln p'(u).
\end{equation}

However, if I plug \eqref{1} into this expression for the local acceleration, I get

\begin{equation}
\kappa (u) = \frac{2t'(u)\ddot{x}_m}{1-\dot{x}^2_m} = \frac{\ddot{x}_m}{1-\dot{x}^2_m} \tag{*} \label{2}
\end{equation}

where in going to the second equality I have used the fact that $t=(u+v)/2$ with $v\equiv t+x$, so $t'(u)=1/2$.

**Confusion:** I seem to [recall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_acceleration#Acceleration_in_.281.2B1.29D) that, in the unidirectional case, proper acceleration is related to coordinate acceleration via

\begin{equation}
\kappa (u)= \gamma^3 \ddot {x}_m = \frac{\ddot{x}_m}{(1-\dot{x}^2_m)^{3/2}}.
\end{equation}

i.e., it looks to me like \eqref{2} is off by a factor of $\gamma^{-1}$.